# On a Dialog and MessageDialog how can we change the text of buttons in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

Lets suppose we are using a `Dialog` or a `MessageDialog` element, where we have the default buttons. How can we change the text and even use qsTr for translating?

Lets suppose the following `Dialog`

```
Dialog {
    id: dateDialog
    visible: true
    title: "Choose a date"
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Save | StandardButton.Cancel

    onAccepted: console.log("Saving the date " +
        calendar.selectedDate.toLocaleDateString())

    Calendar {
        id: calendar
        onDoubleClicked: dateDialog.click(StandardButton.Save)
    }
}
```

and `MessageDialog`:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

MessageDialog {
    title: "Overwrite?"
    icon: StandardIcon.Question
    text: "file.txt already exists.  Replace?"
    detailedText: "To replace a file means that its existing contents will be lost. " +
        "The file that you are copying now will be copied over it instead."
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.YesToAll |
        StandardButton.No | StandardButton.NoToAll | StandardButton.Abort
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    onYes: console.log("copied")
    onNo: console.log("didn't copy")
    onRejected: console.log("aborted")
}
```

As we can see it uses `StandardButton` this is the one i want the text customizable.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem calling the method

```
myDialog.standardButton(Dialog.Ok).text = qsTrId("Ok")
```

in `Component.onCompleted`